# tx_news: link to pdf in list view

Tags: typo3, tx-news

I'm tyring to set up list view with tx_news and want to link a pdf file, that is also used as thumbnail directly in list view, not in detail view.
Tried

```
<a href="{relatedFile.originalResource.publicUrl -> f:format.htmlspecialchars()}" target="_blank">
```

But the link remains empty... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet as is looks ok, maybe the the loop around this link might not be in Order.

It should have structure like this:

```
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem">
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.falMedia}">
        <f:then>
            <f:for each="{newsItem.falRelatedFiles}" as="falfile" iteration="i">
                <li>
                    <span class="news-related-files-link">
                        <a href="{falfile.originalResource.publicUrl -> f:format.htmlspecialchars()}" target="_blank">
                            {falfile.originalResource.title}
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="news-related-files-size">
                        {falfile.originalResource.size -> f:format.bytes()}
                    </span>
                    <f:format.html>
                        falimage.uid     : {falimage.uid}
                        identifier       : {falimage.originalResource.identifier}
                        public_url       : {falimage.originalResource.publicUrl}
                        name             : {falimage.originalResource.name}
                        title            : {falimage.originalResource.title}
                        alternative      : {falimage.originalResource.alternative}
                        description      : {falimage.originalResource.description}
                        extension        : {falimage.originalResource.extension}
                        type             : {falimage.originalResource.type}
                        mimeType         : {falimage.originalResource.mimeType}
                        size             : {falimage.originalResource.size}
                        creationTime     : {falimage.originalResource.creationTime}
                        modificationTime : {falimage.originalResource.modificationTime}
                    </f:format.html>
                </li>
            </f:for>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
        </f:else>
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

Comment: thanks.
The result is, that only the filesize is viewed. The title and link are not displayed...

Comment: ok, than you need to debug the falfile-attributes, will update my answer.

Comment: just saw a small error in the link - should work now.

Comment: Glad that helped! Please, mark this question as solved then.